# DOMDocument->loadHTMLFile() I/O warning : failed to load external entity, only fails when called by ajax

Tags: php

I have a function which creates a new instance of a form template I've made (not using a template engine) and fills it in with various data based on an object thats passed to it. I use this function to create forms for existing objects when the page is loaded, but I also have a button in the interface which makes an ajax request to a separate script which creates a new object and then calls that function to create a form for the object to be sent as a response to the ajax.

The error is:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;templates/form_edit_event.html&quot; in C:\wamp64\www\<private>\src\<private>\components\component_edit_event.php on line 12
```

The code it references:

```
11    $eventDom = new DOMDocument();
12    $eventDom->loadHTMLFile('templates/form_edit_event.html');
```

The thing is though, when the page is first loaded, my script and the loadHTMLFile function work just fine to create the forms for the already existing objects. The I/O error only occurs when I use the button to try to make a new one. The exact text of which is as follows, although I obscured some directory names that shouldn't matter:

The files it's loading is pure html, not even a header/footer/etc, just `<form>contents</form>`. I have no idea why it would fail only sometimes.

The entire script (minus some irrelevent use/includes) being called from ajax is this, with `component_edit_event.php` being the script mentioned above which creates the form:

```
include_once __DIR__ . '\..\components\component_edit_event.php';

$tourneyId = $_POST['tourneyId'];
/** @var DimTournament $tourney */
$tourney = DimTournament::findById($tourneyId);
$newEvent = new DimEvent($tourney);
echo createEventForm($newEvent)->saveHTML();
```

I don't think I should need to include any other code but I absolutely can if needed.

Comment: My first guess is that since this is warning and not an error, your first call has some suppression of warning and your second doesn't. Right before line 11, can your force all errors on using `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to test this?

Comment: Nope, nothing on the initial calls still. They load and render just fine. Calls made via the button give the warning, give some other errors as a result of `$eventDom` being null, and don't render anything except the errors.

I even tried adding that line to some other places where I thought it might do something but nope.

Comment: maybe you have some ownerships issues have you checked that your file is readable by your script?

Comment: Its already being read multiple times. My main document has a `for(){ createEventForm() }` which calls the exact same function multiple times to create the initial page.

Comment: Actually that seems to have been the issue. The relative path in the loadHTMLFile() was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping the relative path in `$eventDom->loadHTMLFile('templates/form_edit_event.html');` to an absolute path fixed the issue. The script that was throwing the error was in a different directory from the script which was working fine.

I'll be making a config file with some sort of $srcRoot variable for the sake of keeping some semblance of pseudo-relativity in the path names.

Comment: That's a fun little bug to figure out! All (or almost all) of PHP's include system has some [hidden surprises](https://cjhaas.com/2019/05/21/php-include-path-surprises/) (and I'd argue security problems) when using relative paths, so if you can make it absolute somehow, I'd do that.

Comment: Yeah, it was just a matter of remembering that include is really just a textual replace like in C and realizing that the paths don't make sense when included in other files.